# You must construct ASCII Pylons!

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

<sub>*[Cross posted from my anagolf post (note: may contain spoilers, post mortem).](http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?ASCII+Pylon)*</sub>

Output the following text exactly.

- You may have additional trailing whitespace on each line, and trailing newlines as well.
- Shortest code, in bytes, wins.

```
                                                
                                              !"!
                                             "#$#"
                                            #$%&%$#
                                           $%&'('&%$
                                          %&'()*)('&%
                                         &'()*+,+*)('&
                                        '()*+,-.-,+*)('
                                       ()*+,-./0/.-,+*)(
                                      )*+,-./01210/.-,+*)
                                     *+,-./012343210/.-,+*
                                    +,-./0123456543210/.-,+
                                   ,-./01234567876543210/.-,
                                  -./0123456789:9876543210/.-
                                 ./0123456789:;<;:9876543210/.
                                /0123456789:;<=>=<;:9876543210/
                               0123456789:;<=>?@?>=<;:9876543210
                              123456789:;<=>?@ABA@?>=<;:987654321
                             23456789:;<=>?@ABCDCBA@?>=<;:98765432
                            3456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFEDCBA@?>=<;:9876543
                           456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHGFEDCBA@?>=<;:987654
                          56789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJIHGFEDCBA@?>=<;:98765
                         6789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLKJIHGFEDCBA@?>=<;:9876
                        789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNMLKJIHGFEDCBA@?>=<;:987
                       89:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@?>=<;:98
                      9:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@?>=<;:9
                     :;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@?>=<;:
                    ;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@?>=<;
                   <=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@?>=<
                  =>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@?>=
                 >?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@?>
                ?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@?
               @ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@
              ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`aba`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
             BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdcba`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCB
            CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefedcba`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDC
           DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghgfedcba`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFED
          EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijihgfedcba`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFE
         FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklkjihgfedcba`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGF
        GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnmlkjihgfedcba`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHG
       HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnoponmlkjihgfedcba`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIH
      IJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrqponmlkjihgfedcba`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJI
     JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstsrqponmlkjihgfedcba`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJ
    KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLK
   LMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONML
  MNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONM
 NOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|{zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPON
OPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~}|{zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPO
```

Comment: Is there an intentional first whitespace-only line?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork that's a space because that's the first ASCII char lol

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Oh, durr. lol

Comment: *(note: may contain spoilers, post mortem).* then don't click where the submissions are. :P

Comment: Plus points for the `_^ emoji.

Comment: @the4kman and the `<=>=<` fish.

Comment: Is an additional leading newline permitted? Can we output an array of lines? How about an array of character arrays?

Comment: Are leading spaces allowed? (equal amount of spaces on each line)

Comment: @Cowsquack Nope.

Comment: What about the additional leading newline I asked about?

Comment: @Shaggy I'm going to have to say no, I think.

Comment: Is there a reason this isn't titled "You Must Construct ASCII Pylons!"?

Comment: @mattdm I can change it, that's better haha

Comment: @mattdm I only came here from the HNQ list to upvote this because of its title. Nicely done.

Comment: I don't understand the title...

Comment: @EsolangingFruit It's a variation of a starcraft meme: [You must construction additional pylons!](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/you-must-construct-additional-pylons)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>15</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
0ｃ［Ｃ²［ｊ｝¹ｍ］／││
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=MCV1RkY0MyV1RkYzQiV1RkYyMyVCMiV1RkYzQiV1RkY0QSV1RkY1RCVCOSV1RkY0RCV1RkYzRCV1RkYwRiV1MjUwMiV1MjUwMg__,v=2)

Note that while making this I added a couple built-ins (`ｃ` & `Ｃ`) as Canvas somehow didn't have any built-ins for ASCII/unicode before...

Explanation (some characters have been replaced to look monospace):

```
0c              push the charcode of "0" - 48
  {       ]     map over 1..48
   C              push the ASCII characters
    ²[ ]          repeat by the counter (0-indexed)
      j             remove the last character
        ¹m        mold to the length of the counter
           /    pad each line with spaces so it looks like a diagonal
            ││  palindromize the whole thing horizontally
```

Answer (score 16):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 73 bytes

```powershell
' '*48;46..0|%{" "*$_+-join[char[]](($x=79-$_)..($y=$x+$j++)+(++$y)..$x)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X11BXcvEwtrETE/PoEa1WklBSUslXls3Kz8zLzo5I7EoOjZWQ0OlwtbcUlclXlNPT0Ol0lalQlslS1tbU1tDW1ulEiioUqFZ@/8/AA)

Outputs the first whitespace-only line, then loops from `46` to `0`. Each iteration, outputs the corresponding number of spaces and then a `-join`ed together `char`-array of the appropriate symbols, via some calculations.

Comment: Can you save some calculations by treating the first line as 47 spaces followed by a space character?

Comment: @Riking To do so, you'd need to special case how the char-array is created to only create one item instead of 3 or more. As a result, it's shorter to special case the spaces-only line completely separately.

Answer (score 11):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
Ｅ⁴⁸⮌✂γι⊕⊗ι‖Ｏ←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUDDxEJHISi1LLWoOFUjOCczOVUjXUchU0fBMy@5KDU3Na8kNUXDJb80KQdIZ2qCgDVXUGpaTmpyiT9QVw7QCCuf1LQSTev////rluUAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 ⁴⁸             Literal 48
Ｅ               Map over implicit range
      ι  ι      Current index
        ⊗       Doubled
       ⊕        Incremented
     γ          Printable ASCII
    ✂           Slice
   ⮌            Reverse
                Implicitly print each slice on separate lines
          ‖Ｏ←   Reflect with overlap
```

Comment: The output seems wrong to me.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Ugh, classic off-by-1 error...

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 73 bytes

```python
i=48
while i:i-=1;r=range(79-i,127-i*2);print' '*i+bytearray(r+r[-2::-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLCoAgEADQfadw56dmoQSW4kmihYHkQJgMQnh6e6/2lt9ixsCwbtOX8UkMHULQngLFcidhd8BFGwuojPSVsDTOuML56i1FotgFzXSAcQ70Kcf4AQ) Crossposted from anarchy golf (see [my submission](http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?ASCII+Pylon/lynn_1523517333&py)).

Quick post-mortem analysis: xnor and dianne discovered the [exact](http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?ASCII+Pylon/xnor_1523583184&py) same [solution](http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?ASCII+Pylon/dianne_1523778547&py). ebicochneal submitted a [71 byte solution](http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?ASCII+Pylon/ebicochineal_1523764377&py) which mitchs improved to [70 bytes](http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?ASCII+Pylon/mitchs_1524714112&py). They avoid dealing with `bytearray` (which is long) or `''.join(map(chr,…))` (which is even longer) entirely, by keeping a "current line" variable and cleverly updating it.

Answer (score 4):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), <s>16</s> 15 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
'½{ ~Δf⌡kFm}⁰¼╥
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JTI3JUJEJTdCJTIwJTdFJXUwMzk0ZiV1MjMyMWtGbSU3RCV1MjA3MCVCQyV1MjU2NQ__,v=0.12)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
48ḶḤr$z0ZUŒB+32ỌY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/E4uGObQ93LClSqTKICj06yUnb2Ojh7p7I//8B)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 16 bytes

```
48FžQNÝûN+èJ}).C
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fxMLt6L5Av8NzD@/20z68wqtWU8/5/38A)

Comment: Ahhh... `žQ` was way better than `žw79ŸvyžwN2*+ŸûçJ}).C`

Answer (score 3):

## VBA, 71 bytes

An anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs to the console.

```vb
For i=0To 47:?Spc(47-i);:For j=-i To i:?Chr(32-Abs(j)+2*i);:Next:?:Next
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 110 bytes

```lisp
(dotimes(i 48)(dotimes(j 96)(princ(if(>(abs(- j 48))i)" "(code-char(+(-(* i 2)(abs(- j 48)))32)))))(princ"
"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzNCkBAFEb3nuI2q@@j2SCx8S5jkCt/Ge8/klLO7tTp@EXDESP6/dJ1CFApa342S1MRx6mbh45o4boAK/MTUWnEwO/9YP3kTmSwSEUl5y9jkfPh3ZjEkDHe)

#### Explanation

```lisp
(dotimes(i 48)                   ;; for i from 0 up to 47
    (dotimes(j 96)               ;; for j from 0 up to 95
        (princ                   ;; print
            (if(>(abs(- j 48))i) ;; if abs(j - 48) > i
                " "              ;; print " "
                (code-char(+(-(* i 2)(abs(- j 48)))32)) ;; else print appropriate character
            )
        )
    )(princ"
") ;; print newline
)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 70 bytes

```ruby
s=[*?\s..?~]*'';48.times{|i|puts s[i,i+1].rjust(48)+s.reverse[-2*i,i]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v9g2Wss@plhPz74uVktd3drEQq8kMze1uLoms6agtKRYoTg6UydT2zBWryirtLhEw8RCU7tYryi1LLWoODVa10gLKBtb@/8/AA)

Constructs the full printable ASCII string and then prints the required number of forward (padded with spaces) + backward slices of it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 24 bytes

```
48RrḤ’$$ịØṖŒBṭ"48RU⁶ẋ$¤Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf9qZWxsef//NDhScuG4pOKAmSQk4buLw5jhuZbFkkLhua0iNDhSVeKBtuG6iyTCpFn//w)

Answer (score 2):

## C (gcc), 117 bytes

```
c;i;main(){for(i=0;i<48;++i){for(c=2*i-15;c<32+2*i;++c)putchar(c>31+i?c:32);for(;c>31+i;--c)putchar(c);putchar(10);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYrbCsIwEAV/J2sINImCeJL2W8oBdR@8IPpU@u3blFLwbZgZhhtpRigeoz6dTNfXx2ntoOV4hve6GdZ00BBPYMnJN26J8v59eR9b7XP0OvCSk2DdsRmE8DcJdoydYJ7NFg)

Ungolfed:

```
int ch;
int row;
int main(void) {
    for (row = 0; row < 48; ++row) {
        for (ch = 2*row-15; ch < 32 + 2*row; ++ch) {
            // The first character in the row is 2*row - 15 (row is zero-indexed)
            if (ch > 31+row)
                putchar(ch);
            else
                // If the current character is not in the pyramid, mask it with a space
                putchar(' ');
        }
        for (; ch > 31+row; --ch) {
            // Finish the other side of the pyramid
            putchar(ch);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: [108 bytes](https://tio.run/##RYxJCoAwEAT/4iljCKgRRMflLdKgzsEFl5Pk7THowVtTXRTMCHgPnntZlNA9rLtiqfOSRTfbdR4qiujDaLJYTFowapvosFlrUHAw9eFtA5QOlc2I38pH@DeMIXbO@wc "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>55</s> 53 bytes

```perl6
say ' 'x 47-$_,chrs 32+2*$_ X-(-$_..$_)>>.abs for ^48
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVJBXUG9QsHEXFclXic5o6hYwdhI20hLJV4hQlcDKKanpxKvaWenl5hUrJCWX6QQZ2Lx/z8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>77</s> <s>75</s> 69 bytes

```perl
map{say$"x(47-$_),(@a=map chr$_+32,$_..$_*2),reverse@a[0..@a-2]}0..47
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saC6OLFSRalCw8RcVyVeU0fDIdEWKKqQnFGkEq9tbKSjEq@npxKvZaSpU5RallpUnOqQGG2gp@eQqGsUWwtkmJj///8vv6AkMz@v@L@ur6megaEBAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>114</s> <s>113</s> 107 bytes

```c
#define _(_)for(k=32;k<j;)putchar(j+_++);
f(j,k){for(j=31;++j<80;){printf("\n%*c",80-j,j);_(-31+k)_(j+~k)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBCsIwEADAu6@QirDrJtCaS2HbnwihxEazwVhCPZX49Vjvwzj9cK7W0332Ic1HCxb9O0MczZXjIIzLZ3XPKYOQJUI@eBAVcfsjGU3HRDL0LeO25JBWD80tnS@uUX2rRQmyBW06imj34RuxlPqaQoJ9AORSfw)

*[101 bytes](https://tio.run/##Fc1BCsIwEADAvxSEXTeB1lwK29x8hhBCILUbjaWtpxKfbqwfmAl6DKHWCKIS7vG1gFjTMZEMfcu4z8uUtwjNLZ/OoVF9q0UJsgNtOkroQOiTsJT69FOGQwDkUr8hPvy4Vn21Dhz@2WTNhdMgjPN7C3d/ROSIkH8) are possible using a compiler flag.*

Answer (score 2):

## Japt `-R`, <s>18</s> 15 bytes

[14 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=IzHHb2RIK1rJIKzqw/s=&input=LVI=) if an additional leading newline is allowed.

```
#0õ_odH+ZÉ ¬êÃû
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=IzD1X29kSCtaySCs6sP7&input=LVI=)

---

### Explanation

```
#0                  :48
  õ                 :Range [1,48]
   _         Ã      :Pass each Z through a function
    o               :  Range [0,Z)
      H+ZÉ          :    To each add 32+Z-1
     d              :    Get the character at that codepoint
           ¬        :  Join to a string
            ê       :  Palinrdomise
              û     :Centre pad each element to the length of the longest element
                    :Implicitly join with newlines and output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>47</strike> 44 bytes

```
(,.~}:@|."1)(1+i.48)([|.@{.}.)"0 1 u:31+i.96
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pflFiuYGulYKAAwrp6Cs5BPm7/NXT06mqtHGr0lAw1NQy1M/VMLDQ1omv0HKr1avU0lQwUDBVKrYxBEpZm/zW5UpMz8hWU9IBG/QcA)

Thanks to Conor O'Brien for the template!
Thanks to FrownyFrog for indicating the invalid solution.

Comment: Perhaps this is more easily modifiable: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pflFiuYGulYKAAwrp6Cs5BPm7/NXT06mqtHGr0lAw1NTL1TCw1NaJr9Byq9WysHKJr9WI1lQwUDBVKrYyNtDP1LE3/a3KlJmfkKyjpAU37DwA "J – Try It Online")

Comment: @Conor O'Brien - Thank you for the template, I've updated the link.

Comment: Prints an extra line at the top.

Comment: @FrownyFrog Oh, it's only now that I see that only trailing newlines are permitted, not leading. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: @FrownyFrog - Fixed and slightly golfed.

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 153 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @ INT=33,@t CHAR(95)=''a:PRINT @t;
SET @t=LEFT(STUFF(STUFF(@t,63-@/2,2,''),46,0,CHAR(@-1)+CHAR(@)+CHAR(@+1)+CHAR(@)),33+@/2)
SET @+=2IF @<128GOTO a
```

Returns are for display only.

I tried several ideas, including a loop to preconstruct the full string (163 characters), and a nested loop to build it on the fly (168 characters), but this ended up being the shortest.

Basically, each loop I'm *cramming 4 new characters* into the center of the string, then trimming off the extras from both ends, using the [SQL `STUFF()` function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Formatted and explained:

```sql
DECLARE @ INT=33,                      --Using a single counter for both rows and CHAR
        @t CHAR(95)=''                 --a non-null CHAR field will pre-fill with spaces
a:                                     --GOTO loop, shorter than a WHILE
    PRINT @t                           --duh
    SET @t = LEFT(                     --lops off the character at the end
            STUFF(                     --crams 4 new characters in the middle
            STUFF(@t, 63-@/2, 2, '')   --snips out a space and the leading character
                 ,46, 0, CHAR(@-1) + CHAR(@) + CHAR(@+1) + CHAR(@))
                 ,33 + @/2)            --rest of the LEFT()
    SET @+=2
IF @<128 GOTO a
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/),  <s>40 37</s> 32 bytes

40 expression `u:30+2>.(+:@i.@(2&+)(-*(>+:))"0 _|@i:)47` thanks to +Galen Ivanov & +Conor O'Brien for the ideas in their solutions

37 included **echo** `echo u:32+|.(~.(>:*+:@[-])"0 _])|i:47`

```
echo u:32+|.(~.(>:*[+-)"{])|i:47
```

incorporating @FrownyFrog tips from comments

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y/rv56SnkJdfopCYk6OQW6mQX56nUJ5flK2jkJmXnF9UkF@UWJJarFCSWVCskFaUn6vg4FYEVFMJJNP/pyZn5CuUWhkbadfoadTpadhZaUVr62oqVcdq1mRamZj//w8A)

Comment: I don't think expressions are valid submissions.

Comment: @LyricLy , opinion seems to vary as I do see another J answer in this form .. anyway thanks for prodding me to shave another 8 bytes .. now I have room to add "echo " : hope you're happy : )

Comment: ``"0 _`` → ``"{``

Comment: ``+:@[-]`` → ``[+-``

Comment: beautiful .. thanks for these tips @FrownyFrog

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 59 bytes

```
48.times{|i|-47.upto(i){|c|putc~c<i ?32-c.abs+2*i:32};puts}
```

Cross-posted from my answer on anagol.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>98</s> 88 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @Mr.Xcoder

```python
i=32
exec"print''.join(chr(i+i-32-abs(j))for j in range(32-i,i-31)).center(95);i+=1;"*48
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYlNDoMgGAX3noKwEepPorZJG@NJGheIgB8mYAGT9vQUuuri5U1mjk/YrOljhGnoC/EWHB8OTCjLVlswhG@OQAXN0Dds8URTKq1DGoFBjhklSApQp95R2nJhgnDkcaMjVFM34sv1HuMTs4WvuEZYwO7y21NqPBcpvJwP2Zw7E5BBSmvtr6nNrzIt20QqTf6xwvMX)

Comment: `-i+32` => `32-i` and you might use `' '*(79-i)` instead of `.center(95)` to save bytes.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder thanks! `' '*(79-i)+` doesn't really save bytes :D

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 95 bytes

```javascript
f=(x=y=0)=>y<48?[`
`[x]]+Buffer([x<48-y|x>48+y?32:x<48?x+y*2-16:80-x+y*2])+f(++x%96?x:+!++y):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcjdCoIwFADg@96ii3DrsDATmaM56DXGQLFNCnGiFedA775@7j6@e/fq1n65zQ8xxatPKWiGmnTOdUPnUhrbblqLzsHlGYJfmMXvCnpjU0ogcyrULwwC7QtxrJTMxd@OQ2AAuKsrgwq2AMRVlqU@Tmsc/WGMAwuM8/QB)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 78 bytes

```ruby
s=*32;48.times{puts (s.map(&:chr)*'').center 95;c=*s[0]+1;s=c+s.map{|x|x+2}+c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v9hWy9jI2sRCryQzN7W4uqC0pFhBo1gvN7FAQ80qOaNIU0tdXVMvOTWvJLVIwdLUOtlWqzjaIFbb0LrYNlkbrLC6pqKmQtuoVju59v9/AA)

Full program. Ungolfed:

```ruby
s=*32;                              # s is an array of integers
48.times{                           # Repeat 48 times:
  puts (s.map(&:chr)*'').center 95; # Turn each int to a char, join, center, and print
  c = *s[0] + 1;                    # c is a singleton array. It will bookend the next line
  s = c + s.map{|x|x+2} + c         # Add 2 to each element of s before adding the bookends
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 80 bytes

An anonymous [yabasic](/questions/tagged/yabasic) function that takes no input and outputs to the console

```vb
For i=0To 47
For j=i To 47?" ";Next
For j=-i To i?Chr$(32-Abs(j)+2*i);Next
?Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3y2/SCHT1iAkX8HEnAvEybLNVADz7JUUlKz9UitKoMK6YPFMe@eMIhUNYyNdx6RijSxNbSOtTE2IMnsQ@f8/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [uBASIC](https://github.com/EtchedPixels/ubasic), 95 bytes

```
0ForI=0To47
1ForJ=ITo47:?" ";:NextJ
2ForK=-1*IToI:?Left$(Chr$(32-Abs(K)+2*I),1);:NextK
3?:NextI
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/fwC2/yNPWICTfxJzLEMj2svUEsa3slRSUrK38UitKvLiMgOLetrqGWkApTyt7n9S0EhUN54wiFQ1jI13HpGINb01tIy1PTR1DTYgWby5jezDD8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MY-BASIC](https://github.com/paladin-t/my_basic), 97 bytes

An anonymous MY-BASIC response that takes no input and outputs to the Console

```vb
For i=0 To 47
For j=i To 47
Print" "
Next
For j=-i To i
Print Chr(32-Abs(j)+2*i)
Next
Print;
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y63UTUoszkz@/98tv0gh09ZAISRfwcScC8TLss2E8gKKMvNKFJQUlLj8UitKoJK6YNlMqKRzRpGGsZGuY1KxRpamtpFWpiZELVjWGsz@/x8A)

-1 byte thanks to [Jonathan Frech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73111/jonathan-frech)

Comment: `Print " "` -> `Print" "`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech - whoops sorry I mispelled your name

Answer (score 1):

#### C (gcc) 199 bytes

```
#include<stdio.h>
int i,j=32,k=32,l=49;int main(){while(k<127){for(i=0;i<l;++i)printf(" ");for(i=j;i<k;++i)printf("%c",i);printf("%c",k);for(i=k-1;i>=j;--i)printf("%c",i);printf("\n");j++;k+=2;l--;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYxBCsIwFET3nqJEhIQkYmtB5Cc9iRtJW/uTmEqtuCg9e0wRQRduBmbezBh5MSbGNQbjH3Wj7mON/barVhjGDIXV@0K4Rbwuj7CE1zMGyqZnh76hTuXFgU1tP1DUO0DlgXNktyE1W0oywuDNbGLuh20MEcjg27pP28kcsEojKf8OTiGdW87BcV2AlxLmOcYX)

Thanks to Picard and PunPun1000 for all of the help

Comment: @Picard I removed the spaces. I could further minify with a global iterator variable.

Comment: @Picard I edited it on my phone; didn't realize I'd left a blank line.

Comment: There's unnecessary spaces in the printf calls after the commas, and the variable names can be shortened down to one letter.  Also it would be nice if you could include a TIO link and the actual byte count.  Here's the link for your current code [TIO](https://tio.run/##dc5BD4IgFMDxe5@C2dpgSEtra@2Jn6SLQ8y3KTqhOjg/O4nWwUMnYPv9H0@Jh1Le79Go5llqkllXYnes8x0aRzC2rhicPKexfmkTTtsXSlt5uUEAbYGGsvFdY6NpIFmSXtlYdQNFeQLMVg6cI@uHuahoRCIGK1iGzyiEG3JQUUyQweYd1K8Md5EA5t8ZQvyP72b@cGGcQwi5TGHdSwiYJu8/)

Comment: ok, i've squeezed it a bit more, i think i'd have to change the algorithm to shrink it further

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 18 bytes

```
48:"@@Zv30++Xhc3Zu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38TCSsnBIarM2EBbOyIj2Tiq9P9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>115</s> <s>114</s> 110 bytes

```java
()->{for(int m=0,c;m<48;m++)for(c=-48;++c<m+2;)System.out.print(c<-m?' ':c>m?'\n':(char)(32-(c<0?-c:c)+2*m));}
```

- `(c<0?-c:c)` saves 1 byte over `Math.abs(c)`
- I used `?:` to print spaces before the pylon and a newline after it to save multiple `System.out.print` calls.

Comment: Is omitting the class declaration permitted? :)

Comment: @Trejkaz [It is allowed to submit a full program or a function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/64121).

Comment: `for(c=-47;c<m+2;c++){...}` -> `for(c=-48;++c<m+2;)...`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Done.  Thanks.

Comment: @rgettman You can most likely also get rid of the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), <s>129</s> <s>122</s> <s>118</s> 117 bytes

```
time {incr i;set j -48;set a {};time {set a $a[format %c [expr abs([incr j])>=$i?32:$i*2-abs($j)+30]]} 96;puts $a} 48
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/JDM3VaE6My@5SCHTuji1RCFLQdfEAsxKVKiutYbIQ7gqidFp@UW5iSUKqskK0akVBUUKiUnFGtFg3Vmxmna2Kpn2xkZWKplaRrogGZUsTW1jg9jYWgVLM@uC0pJioBG1CiYW//8DAA)

#### Explanation

```
time { # for i from 0 up to 47
    incr i
    set j -48
    set a {}
    time { # for j from -48 up to 47
        # add next character to a
        set a $a[format %c [expr abs([incr j])>$i?32:$i*2-abs($j)+32]]
    } 96
    puts $a # print a
} 48
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 29 bytes

```
`0FaLssLF:P|LF:M|`/L-R` lRo|;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/P8HALdGnuNjHzSqgBkj41iTo@@gGJSjkBOXXWP//DwA)

#### How it works

```
`0FaLssLF:P|LF:M|`/L-R` lRo|;

`0F                        |;  Repeat the following 48 times and halt...
   a                           Push 10 (\n)
    Lss                        Push L(loop counter) + 32
       LF:P|                   Repeat "Clone the top and increment" L times
            LF:M|              Repeat "Clone the top and decrement" L times
                 `/L-R`        Push 32 (space) 47-L times (space is significant)
                        lRo    Print everything as char, from the top,
                               until the stack is empty
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 102 bytes

```hs
main=putStr$do
i<-[48,47..0]
let l=replicate i 32++[79-i..126-i*2]
map toEnum$l++tail(reverse l)++[10]
```

Things I have tried that were not shorter:

- Expressing everything in terms of character literals and `succ` or `pred` to save the `map toEnum`.
- Writing a downward range instead of using `reverse`.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 94 bytes

```php
for(;49>$k=++$i;printf("%47s%s
",$s,substr(strrev($s),1)))for($s="";$k--;)$s.=chr(30+$i*2-$k);
```

Run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/63eef00cdeaec5ff319fa9ce6672539f78f9a3ac).

Answer (score 0):

## Deadfish~, 6049 bytes

```
{iii}ii{cc}{cc}cccccccc{dd}ddc{ii}ii{cc}{cc}ccccccicicdc{dd}dddc{ii}ii{cc}{cc}ccccciicicicdcdc{dd}ddddc{ii}ii{cc}{cc}cccciiicicicicdcdcdc{dd}dddddc{ii}ii{cc}{cc}ccciiiicicicicicdcdcdcdc{dd}ddddddc{ii}ii{cc}{cc}cciiiiicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdc{ddd}iiic{ii}ii{cc}{cc}ciiiiiicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdc{ddd}iic{ii}ii{cc}{cc}{i}dddcicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{ddd}ic{ii}ii{cc}{c}ccccccccc{i}ddcicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{ddd}c{ii}ii{cc}{c}cccccccc{i}dcicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{ddd}dc{ii}ii{cc}{c}ccccccc{i}cicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{ddd}ddc{ii}ii{cc}{c}cccccc{i}icicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{ddd}dddc{ii}ii{cc}{c}ccccc{i}iicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{ddd}ddddc{ii}ii{cc}{c}cccc{i}iiicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{ddd}dddddc{ii}ii{cc}{c}ccc{i}iiiicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{ddd}ddddddc{ii}ii{cc}{c}cc{i}iiiiicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{dddd}iiic{ii}ii{cc}{c}c{i}iiiiiicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{dddd}iic{ii}ii{cc}{c}{ii}dddcicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{dddd}ic{ii}ii{cc}ccccccccc{ii}ddcicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{dddd}c{ii}ii{cc}cccccccc{ii}dcicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{dddd}dc{ii}ii{cc}ccccccc{ii}cicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{dddd}ddc{ii}ii{cc}cccccc{ii}icicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{dddd}dddc{ii}ii{cc}ccccc{ii}iicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{dddd}ddddc{ii}ii{cc}cccc{ii}iiicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{dddd}dddddc{ii}ii{cc}ccc{ii}iiiicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{dddd}ddddddc{ii}ii{cc}cc{ii}iiiiicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{ddddd}iiic{ii}ii{cc}c{ii}iiiiiicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{ddddd}iic{ii}ii{cc}{iii}dddcicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{ddddd}ic{ii}ii{c}ccccccccc{iii}ddcicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{ddddd}c{ii}ii{c}cccccccc{iii}dcicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{ddddd}dc{ii}ii{c}ccccccc{iii}cicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{ddddd}ddc{ii}ii{c}cccccc{iii}icicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{ddddd}dddc{ii}ii{c}ccccc{iii}iicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{ddddd}ddddc{ii}ii{c}cccc{iii}iiicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{ddddd}dddddc{ii}ii{c}ccc{iii}iiiicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{ddddd}ddddddc{ii}ii{c}cc{iii}iiiiicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{dddddd}iiic{ii}ii{c}c{iii}iiiiiicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{dddddd}iic{ii}ii{c}{iiii}dddcicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{dddddd}ic{ii}iiccccccccc{iiii}ddcicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{dddddd}c{ii}iicccccccc{iiii}dcicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{dddddd}dc{ii}iiccccccc{iiii}cicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{dddddd}ddc{ii}iicccccc{iiii}icicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{dddddd}dddc{ii}iiccccc{iiii}iicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{dddddd}ddddc{ii}iicccc{iiii}iiicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{dddddd}dddddc{ii}iiccc{iiii}iiiicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{dddddd}ddddddc{ii}iicc{iiii}iiiiicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{{d}iii}iiic{ii}iic{iiii}iiiiiicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc{{d}iii}iic{{i}ddd}dcicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc
```